# I want to search an element of the string str in the string s but when I'm trying to search anything(e.g. str[1]) in the string s, it returns 0

Tags: c, string, algorithm, loops, find

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int lsearch(char a[],int l,int h,char p)
{
   int i=l;
   for(i=l;i<=h;i++)
      if(a[i]==p)
        return i;
      else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
   int i,z;
   char s[100];
   scanf("%s",s);
   char str[100];
   scanf("%s",str);
   z=lsearch(s,0,strlen(s)-1,str[1]);
   printf("%d",z);
}
```

I want to search an element of the string str in the string s but when I'm trying to search anything(e.g. str[1]) in the string s, it returns 0

Comment: And try to indent your code, to improve readability (you would also spot that your for loop has no block delimiter).

Comment: @Fabio_MO what makes you think `for` necessarily needs brackets?

Comment: @Fabio_MO no it doesn't. just the "else" is wrong. he wants to check all chars, not just the first one (after indenting the code this is obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *continue* the loop when the element is not found. The function currently returns on first mismatch.

Something like:

```
    ...

    for(i=l;i<=h;i++) {
        if(a[i]==p) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note that I changed to return `-1` on failure because `0` could also be the index where the char is found.

Answer (score 1):

If to rewrite your for loop with using braces then it looks like

```
for(i=l;i<=h;i++)
{
    if(a[i]==p)
        return i;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

So it is seen that if the first (at position `l`) character of the source string is not equal to the target character the function returns 0.

Also it is a bad approach to return 0 becaues the parameter `L` can be initially set to 0 by the user. In this case it is unclear whether the character is found or not.

Moreover the position should have the type `size_t` and the source character array should be specified with the qualifier `const` because it is not changed in the function.

The function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t lsearch( const char s[], size_t n, char c )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && s[i] != c ) ++i;

    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello Utkarsh Pandey";
    size_t start_pos = 6;
    size_t n = 7;

    size_t pos = lsearch( s + start_pos, n, 'a' );

    if ( pos != n )
    {
        printf( "The character 'a' is found at position %zu\n", pos + start_pos );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "The character 'a' is not found" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The character 'a' is found at position 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop exits after **ONLY** one check: It will `return` `0` for first `return i` or `0` for second `return 0`.

```
for(i=l;i<=h;i++)
{
    if(a[i]==p)
        return i;  // 0
    else
       return 0;   // 0
}
```

The loop should go on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    int lsearch(char a[], int l, int h, char p)
    {
        int i;    
        for(i=l; i < h; i++){

            if( a[i] == p){
                return i;
            }
        }
       return -1;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int i,z;
        char s[100];

        scanf("%s",s);

        char str[100];
        scanf("%s",str);

        z = lsearch(s, 0 ,strlen(s), str[1]);

        printf("%d",z);
    }
```

test:

```
12345                                                                                                                                       
13                                                                                                                                          
2
```